# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Getting the error in  browser-console

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
```

on following line(in bundled js file)

```
ChannelForm.propTypes = {
  addChannel: _react2['default'].PropTypes.func.isRequired 
};
```

my code  looks like this where i'm getting this error

```
ChannelForm.propTypes={
      addChannel: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Everything seems to be fine. I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: are you importing `PropTypes` on the page where you are using ?

Comment: If you're importing Proptypes as a separate module just use: `addChannel: PropTypes.func.isRequired`

Comment: What vesion of react you are using?

Comment: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`  `ChannelForm.propTypes={}`

Answer (score 3):

As says in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5.
>   Please use the prop-types library instead.

so you need to import it first like :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

and then use it where ever you will require propTypes like this (You can modify it accordingly)

```
propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

`React.PropTypes` no longer works. According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html),

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

So you have to import `PropTypes` from the `prop-types` package rather, and then instead of writing `React.PropTypes.func.isRequired` try `PropTypes.func.isRequired`